# Is MongoDB C# Driver LINQ Query Syntax missing Async method?

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

LINQ **method syntax** do have Async method like this:

```
var peter = await peopleCollection.Find(x => x.Name == "Peter").FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

But it doesn't exist in the **query syntax**, like this:

```
var peter = await (from x in collection.AsQueryable()
                   where x.Name == "Peter"
                   select x).FirstOrDefaultAsync(); //COMPILETIME ERROR
```

Is that really true?

An important note if you wanna test: If you have referenced the **Entity Framework** library and have the **using System.Data.Entity;** statement, then **FirstOrDefaultAsync()** exist at compile-time, but it will give and error when it runs.

Comment: Should that not be `query = from .....; ` and then `peter = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync()`? AFAIK you don't actually wrap a query definition like that.

Comment: Hi Neil Lunn :-) The reason i wrap it in parenthesis, is because then i can retrieve the object in one statement. The thing you suggested works the same way, but then it would take two statements. Other than that, there wouldn't be any difference. I also just tested the thing you suggested, and the FirstOrDefaultAsync() still doesn't exist.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

FirstOrDefaultAsync (and many others) are supported. I believe your issue may be that you are not including MongoDB.Driver.Linq, where the extension methods are defined.

Tests are here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/tests/MongoDB.Driver.Tests/Linq/MongoQueryableTests.cs#L309.

Code is here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/src/MongoDB.Driver/Linq/MongoQueryable.cs

Answer (score 0):

Probably, your returned type is an **IQueryable** interface. You should use   `MongoDB.Driver.Linq.IMongoQueryable<T>` interface instead of it.